# Update large table with count(*) values from another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Items has the fields id,title,number. The relevant field (list) in the other table (lists) is one with comma-separated values which are IDs from items. I want items.number to be the same as the count of times the relevant ID appears in the lists table. As an example, this query is working fine to achieve this...

```
update items set number = (select count(*) from lists where list like concat('%',items.id,'%')) where title > 'Z'
```

But if I want to update the whole of items (or even just titles beginning with 'Y', say, where there are a lot more than the mere 200 starting with Z), I get errors - either 'MySQL server has gone away' or 'Query execution was interrupted'. I assume this is because the query is too demanding. Is there a better way to achieve this without the server going splat?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say, items has about 100,000 entries

Comment: Why store this value at all?

Comment: Well, number is used a lot in various calculations and it's more efficient for me to grab that figure than run a count(*) on the other table every time I need it

Comment: count(*) is a quite cheap operation, anyway, and you can easily cache in within your application rather within the database

Comment: I see what you mean, but my PHP script would need the count(*) values for different ids about 50+ times each time it runs - not so cheap then alas!

Comment: if you have a recent version of mysql, you can use the WITH ROLLUP clause to get all counts of a certain subset of your data. Just do some research about this clause, and then decide if it can help you (e.g. to prepare a table with count-aggregates and use this table as a lookup table)

Answer (score 1):

Well, bad performance is the price that you pay for a poorly designed data structure.  Here is your query:

```
update items
    set number = (select count(*)
                  from lists
                  where list like concat('%',items.id,'%')
                 )
     where title > 'Z';
```

The `list like` statement suggests that you are storing item ids as a list  By the way, you should include the delimiter in the statement, so you don't get mismatches like 1 matching `'10,11,12'`:

```
where concat(',', list, ',') like concat('%,', items.id, ',%')
```

(assuming comma as a delimiter), or:

```
where find_in_set(items.id, list) > 0;
```

That said, I can't think of a way to speed up this part of the query.  The right solution is to have an association table, called something like `ListItems`, with one row per list and item in the list.  Then you could use equi-joins and indexes to speed up the query.

Comment: I concede an association table would be a better structure - but if there are any ways to speed things up without that I'd prefer it. (The delimiter thing isn't actually a problem as in this case all the IDs are long and of the same length, but I take your point.)

Comment: there is a quote missing in `concat('%,`

But if you are add the seperator like this, don't you exclude the first and the last id, since the have no leading/tailing seperator?